# Erro mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php

Estou a criar um código em html e php onde me aparece o erro "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ", este código irá mostrar pontuaçoes para um torneio de minigolfe. o cógigo da-me erro no código abaixo.

```
<?php
        if($total){ do {
            $query1 = "SELECT nome from jogador WHERE nometeam = ".$linha['nometeam']; 
            $dados1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
            $linha1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados1);
print $query1
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um erro na finalização do código, tente assim.

```
<table class = "tabela" style="width:100%" border="0" bgcolor="white" style="text-align:center;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Equipa</th>
    <th>Jogador</th>
  </tr>
<tbody>
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT `equipa`,`nome` from `jogador` WHERE `nometeam` = '".$linha['nometeam']."'";

$dados1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

while($linha1 = mysqli_fetch_array($dados1)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $linha1['equipa'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $linha1['nome'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Funcionou mas olhe o codigo da tabela toda

Comment: Atualmente, só me é apresentado um jogador por cada equipa. Eu queria saber como fasso para me apresentar 3 jogadores por equipa?

Comment: Você tem na sua tabela "nometeam" 3 registros (jogadores) cadastrados? Pois no while por  não haver condição de restrição/limite de resultado, o while exibe todos, caso queira fazer uma limitação você deve adicionar depois de WHERE `nometeam` = '".$linha['nometeam']."' LIMIT 3, por exemplo.

Comment: sim, tenho 3 jogadores para 3 tabelas

Comment: Se são tabelas distintas você deve fazer o mesmo código para cada tabela, o que não é recomendável, o mais correto seria você inserir todos os jogadores na mesma tabela e diferenciando apenas o nome do tipo com uma coluna "nomedaequipa", por exemplo.

Comment: o nome das equipas e o nome dos jogadores estao na mesma tabela(tabela jogador)

Comment: Na resposta apresentada por mim, o código exibirá todos, talvez seja alguma limitação imposta em seu código, pois na query não inseri nenhuma limitação na quantidades de registro a exibir.

Comment: Confere, alterei o código (minha resposta) para exibir o nome de equipa e jogador com o código da sua tabela, fiz uma alteração semântica, dá uma conferida. Observe que adicionei também o nome da coluna "equipa" na query, adapte para o nome da sua coluna a referente ao "nome da equipa".

Comment: Eu conferi e não tenho limitações no meu código

Comment: Conferiu acima a alteração que fiz na minha resposta? Testa em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento e depois responde aqui.

Comment: conferi e deu nada mesmo